# Custom button hover state in Grommet theme

Tags: reactjs, grommet

Just started using Grommet. I must be missing something obvious because I feel like I'm trying to do something fairly simple. I've created a custom theme, and I'm trying to add a hover state to change the background color of a `Button`. The default hover behavior remains, and the background color does not change.

Here's an abbreviated sample of my code:

```
const customTheme = deepMerge(grommet, {
  global: {
    // colors and such
  },
  button: {
    hover: {
      primary: {
        background: { color: "accent-1" }
      }
    }
  }
};

// then I implement the Button like so
<Grommet theme={customTheme}>
  <Button
    label="My Sad Button"
    primary
  />
</Grommet>
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

UPDATE:

Using the `extend` property as [@Bas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9098350/bas-van-der-linden) suggested does work. I'm still curious why the provided `hover` wouldn't accomplish the same?

UPDATE 2:

As of Feb '21, according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/issues/4111#issuecomment-702157427) in order to make use of the `button.hover.primary` attribute as intended, you must first define values for `button.hover.default`. After defining the `default` values, then the `primary` and/or `secondary` button values seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `extend` attribute on `button`, which value is a function to do something like this:

```
const customTheme = deepMerge(grommet, {
  button: {
    extend: ({ primary }) => {
      if (primary) {
        return `
        &:hover {
          background: ${"#6FFFB0"}; // accent-1 color
        }
      `;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Color reference](https://v2.grommet.io/color)

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-brook-2gznn?file=/src/App.js:217-229)

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know if it works. So, if this is the way to do it, then do you know whey the `hover` theme property doesn't work? Or is that intended for a different purpose?

Comment: I don't know, I couldn't get the other way to work either. Seems like that way or something similar should work from looking at the [documentation of `button`](https://v2.grommet.io/button). Having said this I think the above approach is consistent and flexible as far as theming goes though.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the solution, please find a [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/grommet-button-hover-background-in-theme-yl8bt?file=/index.js) built on [grommet issue 4111](https://github.com/grommet/grommet/issues/4111) mentioned above. It confirms that `default: {}` must be defined in theme for hover to work.

```
const customTheme = deepMerge(grommet, {
  button: {
    default: {}, // this is required for hover below to work
    hover: {
      primary: {
        background: { color: "accent-1" }
      }
    }
  }
});
```